# CLLocationManager Region montoring some times not working on background

Tags: ios, iphone, sdk, cllocationmanager, geofencing

I am using geofencing in CLLocationManager.What doing is
Application in active state call `[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];`and get the current location,then got the nearest location set(max 20),Then it set to region monitoring.Before set the region monitoring i stope all monitored regions using this method

```
for (CLRegion *monitored in [self.locationManager monitoredRegions])
        [self.locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:monitored];
```

Then set the location to the locationmanger.When application goes to background.

```
 [self.locationManager stopUpdateLocation];
      [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

When application in abckground with significant location change then it get the current location and send the location ,get the nearest location set and set it to the region monitoring.In here also i stop the previous monitored regions before set new locations.
problem is some times i have to set same location several times(same lat lon),because user can pass the same location several time when application in background.In that case some times

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
```

this method not calling.Also some times i got region update which i set previous.But i stop all region before i set new one.

any one have idea